# Where is layer mode like "Color Dodge." in Photoshop CS 2?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, adobe-photoshop-elements

I am new to Photoshop. I have searched a lot but didn't find any option like Color Dodge. So will you please help me for that?

I want to make the Photo as [Pencil Sketch](http://www.dwphotoshop.com/photoshop/pencilsketch.php):

[image: Pencil sketch image]

And for that I want that option. I am using Photoshop CS2 for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color Dodge can be found on the Layers Panel:

[image: Layer's Panel]

As well as one the Control Bar with a painting tool selected:

[image]