# How do I use Color Dodge and where do I find it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I was going to do a filter but when I searched it I found that I needed Color Dodge. How do I get to it and what does it do exactly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it has nothing to do with design and can be easily found in your software's help.

Comment: I agree with @Ryan, I found that information with a Google search for "Photoshop Blend Modes" and it was, literally, the very first result.

Comment: @JohnManly to be fair the person asking wouldn't know to search "blend modes," but I opened the Photoshop Online Help from the software and typed in Color Dodge and it was the first result in the help file... Now out of curiosity I did it in Google and the first result (after videos) indicates this should also be closed as a Duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6181/where-is-layer-mode-like-color-dodge-in-photoshop-cs-2

Comment: I've voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Color Dodge is a built-in "filter" (Blend Mode).  See below:

Select the layer you wish to apply the effect to in your Layers Panel and click on the circled drop-down menu:

[image: layers]

Choose Color Dodge

[image]

Adobe explains color dodge on [their site](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/blending-modes.html) as:

> Color Dodge Looks at the color information in each channel and brightens the base color to reflect the blend color by decreasing contrast between the two. Blending with black produces no change.